# onlocationchanged is not called (delay parameter does not apply)

Tags: android, gps, location

in

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time, distance, locationListener);`

I knew that without the priority of time and distance, If it satisfied with either condition is called a `onLocationChanged()`

But `onLocationChanged()` is not called, only called this circumstances.

```
1. Load the page and turns on the gps.
2. location listener catch (0,0) white gps is turned on. (onLocationChanged called)
3. gps is turn on finish.
4. The location listener is called after the time that was 'time' parameter of requestLocationUpdates(). (onLocationChanged called)
5. After... onLocationChanged  is not called never..
```

```
1. If the beginning location is normal value, not (0,0). onLocationChanged  is not ever call. (Even after the time specified in the parameters)
```

Why does not apply to the time parameters of requestLocationUpdates()?

this is my code.

```
private BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    private final String GET_GPS = "getGPS";
    private final String SET_GPS = "setGPS";
    private final String START_GPS = "startGPS";
    private final String FINISH_GPS = "finishGPS";


    Location location;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 *60;
    boolean isGpsMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        if(action.equals(GET_GPS)){
            if(isGPSOn()){
                try {
                    obj.put("result","gpsOn");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else{
                try {
                    obj.put("result","gpsOff");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
        }else if(action.equals(SET_GPS)){
            Intent settingIntent= new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            settingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(settingIntent);
        }else if(action.equals(START_GPS)){
            Log.d("GPS", "GPS Start");
            //stopUsingGPS();
            startCallback();
        }else if(action.equals(FINISH_GPS)){
            Log.d("GPS", "GPS Finish");
            stopUsingGPS();
        }

        if(!(obj.toString().equals("{}"))){
            sendScript("javascript:getGPS" + "(" + obj + ")");  
        }
    }


    public boolean isGPSOn(){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }


    public boolean isNetworkOn(){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        Log.d("GPS", "stopUsingGPS()");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            Log.d("GPS", "lovationManager remove");
        }
    }


    public void startCallback(){
        Log.d("GPS", "startCallback()");
        if(isGpsMode != isGPSOn()){
            if(isGpsMode){
                if(isNetworkOn()){
                    NetworkRegistration();
                }
            }else{
                if(!GPSRegistration()){
                    if(isNetworkOn()){
                        NetworkRegistration();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean GPSRegistration(){
        Log.d("GPS", "call location value from GPS");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
        saveLocation();
        isGpsMode = true;
        Log.d("GPS", "lat: " + String.valueOf(lat)+" / lon: " + String.valueOf(lon));

        return isAvailableLocation(lat, lon);
    }

    public void NetworkRegistration(){
        Log.d("GPS", "call location value from Network");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
        saveLocation();
        isGpsMode = false;
        Log.d("GPS", "lat: " + String.valueOf(lat)+" / lon : " + String.valueOf(lon));
    }

    public void saveLocation(){
        location = null;
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = getLastKnownLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lon = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }

    private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }

    public boolean isAvailableLocation(double lat, double lon){
        if(lon>124 && lon<132 && lat>33 && lat<43){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("GPS", "onLocationChanged - lat: "+lat+" / lon: "+lon);

            if(!(isAvailableLocation(lat, lon))){
                stopUsingGPS();

                if(isGpsMode){ 
                    if(isNetworkOn()){
                        NetworkRegistration();
                        if(isAvailableLocation(lat, lon)){
                            isGpsMode = !isGpsMode;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isGPSOn()){
                        GPSRegistration();
                        if(isAvailableLocation(lat, lon)){
                            isGpsMode = !isGpsMode;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isAvailableLocation(lat, lon)){
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    obj.put("lat", lat);
                    obj.put("lon", lon);
                }catch( JSONException e){
                    Log.d("GPS", "onRegistered: JSON exception");
                }
                sendScript("javascript:sendGPS("+obj+");");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
};
```

The reason I coding like this, it must be in Cordova Activity. (And the boss want it... )

+) I delete comment deliberately, because comment was Korean.. (I'm Korean)
I'm sorry that hard to understand because no comment... :(

All, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer.

**1. onlocationchanged is not called**

This situation is shown when used GPS provider indoors.
When using the GPS provider at room onLocationChange () is not called. (The network provider is operating very successfully.)
So, the value of the gps provider is invalid, must be connected to the network provider.

**2. The Time parameters of requestLocationUpdates() is not apply**

Although not accurate, I think this is probably related to the length of time.
Because, I confirmed to be the working when by the 5 minutes(`1000 * 60 * 5 ms`).

It operates abnormally if shorter than the certain period.
I think Certain period is one minutes`(1000 * 6 ms)`.

If you need, this is my code.

```
private BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    private final String GET_GPS = "getGPS";
    private final String SET_GPS = "setGPS";
    private final String START_GPS = "startGPS";
    private final String FINISH_GPS = "finishGPS";


    LocationManager locationManager;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    boolean isGpsMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        if(action.equals(GET_GPS)){
            if(isGPSOn()){
                try {
                    obj.put("result","gpsOn");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else{
                try {
                    obj.put("result","gpsOff");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
        }else if(action.equals(SET_GPS)){
            Intent settingIntent= new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            settingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(settingIntent);
        }else if(action.equals(START_GPS)){
            Log.d("GPS", "GPS start");
            startCallback();
        }else if(action.equals(FINISH_GPS)){
            Log.d("GPS", "GPS finish");
            stopUsingGPS();
        }

        if(!(obj.toString().equals("{}"))){
            sendScript("javascript:getGPS" + "(" + obj + ")");  
        }
    }

    public boolean isGPSOn(){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    public boolean isNetworkOn(){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        Log.d("GPS", "stopUsingGPS()");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
    }

    public void startCallback(){
        if(isGPSOn()){
            GPSRegistration();
        } else if(isNetworkOn()){
            NetworkRegistration();
        }
    }

    public boolean GPSRegistration(){
        Log.d("GPS", "call location value from GPS");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
        isGpsMode = true;
        Log.d("GPS", "lat: " + String.valueOf(lat)+" / lon: " + String.valueOf(lon));

        return isAvailableLocation(lat, lon);
    }

    public void NetworkRegistration(){
        Log.d("GPS", "call location value from Network");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
        isGpsMode = false;
        Log.d("GPS", "lat: " + String.valueOf(lat)+" / lon: " + String.valueOf(lon));
    }

    public boolean isAvailableLocation(double lat, double lon){
        if(lon>124 && lon<132 && lat>33 && lat<43){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lon = location.getLongitude();
            }

            Log.d("GPS", "onLocationChanged - lat: "+lat+" / lon : "+lon);

            if (isAvailableLocation(lat, lon)) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    obj.put("lat", lat);
                    obj.put("lon", lon);
                }catch( JSONException e){
                    Log.d("GPS", "onRegistered: JSON exception");
                }
                sendScript("javascript:sendGPS("+obj+");");
            } else {
                stopUsingGPS();

                if(isGpsMode){ 
                    if(isNetworkOn()){
                        NetworkRegistration();
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isGPSOn()){
                        GPSRegistration();
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
};
```

And I've coded this code in onCreate(),

`registerReceiver(gpsReceiver, new IntentFilter("actionName"));`

this code in onDestroy().

`unregisterReceiver(gpsReceiver);`

Then, available through

`startIntent(actionName).`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Service instead of BroadcastReceiver for GPS.

Comment: But I used "registerReceiver(gpsReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME));" in onCreate()....